# How to use libCURL on Qt Creator with MSVC2012 as Compiler

Tags: c++, qt, curl, libcurl

Curently I have installed on my system **qt-windows-opensource-5.1.1-msvc2012-x86_64-offline**

All works fine but I cant really succed to use libCurl on my Qt project.

I have downloaded this version of libcurl:
http://curl.haxx.se/download/libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc.zip

```
MSVC metalink   7.19.3  devel   SSL         Frederic Elbin  4.04 MB
```

I have moved include folder from archive to VC include folder and I’ve included in program with **#include**  and works good.

Now on the lib folder are another two folders with names: Debug and Release and both have some files inside.

On my .pro file I have added:

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc/ -llibcurl_imp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc/lib/release/ -lcurllib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc/lib/debug/ -lcurllib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc/lib/Debug
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc/lib/Debug
```

And now when I try to run a simple program I got:

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_curl_easy_init referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)
```

On downloaded archive are more other files too: http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/1416/reh8.png

Probably I’m now including libs fine (internal/external or dynamic/static) and I don’t know which one to include and how. And there are some .dll files too that I don’t know what to do with.

Have someone succesfully used libcurl on Qt projects? I’m beginer on Qt and it’s hard for me…

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us the compilation and linking commands qt creator issues when building your project ? they should be in the compile output pane

Comment: I don't know for sure, where I can get compilation and linking commands?

Comment: press alt + 4 and the compile output pane should come up, qt creator shows you the commands it uses to compile your source code there, you might have this issue because it's issuing wrong compilation commands. You might also get this issue if the lib you are trying to use is compiled for 64 bits and you're using it on a 32 bit project or vice versa. And last but not least you might also find this issue if you are compiling with a different compiler than what curl developers used to compile the lib

Comment: I also have the following problem. In MSVC 2012 everything works fine, but in QtCreator I get the same errors. For static libcurl library, it's look like there is already solution, but for dll library...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I could tell how am I using libCurl in QT. If somone came across this question again.
But I use mingw version, so it might be different.

In .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Users\pagep\QT\curl-7.31.0-devel-mingw32\include
LIBS += C:\Users\pagep\QT\curl-7.31.0-devel-mingw32\lib\libcurldll.a
```

And in "debug" folder (folder where the program is executed) I added .dll files from folder *curl-7.31.0-devel-mingw32\bin*

```
libcurl.dll
libeay32.dll
libidn-11.dll
librtmp.dll
libssh2.dll
ssleay32.dll
zlib1.dll
```

Well it's probably not the best solution but it works for me. :)

Comment: I have installed QtSDK+MinGw and the problem persists. I get this error now: "error: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'"

Comment: I think I know where the problem is. On official download site Qt + MinGw are available only on x86 and libCURL is available for MinGw only on x64. So, I think I need to download and compile libCURL Source as x86. @pagep: can you give me your libcurl folder as archive? Or told me please what version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Solved. I've downloaded everytime wrong version from official libcurl site. This is good version http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.34.0/dist-w32/curl-7.34.0-devel-mingw32.zip

Comment: This is not the answer to the problem because its title is "with MSVC". And this answer is MinGW, not MSVC.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an answer to your question, but I would recommend using QNetworkAccessManager class instead of libcurl. You can do almost anything with this class which you can do using libcurl. Your code will be simpler and more cleaner. Some famous full featured Qt based download managers use this class.

Comment: Yes, I understand that is more native to use QNetworkAccessManager. But is easy for me to use curl, I've used curl before on PHP and is no big difference between php curl and libcurl. I want to use this on Qt and learn how to add libs on my qt project and libcurl is the best example.

Comment: QNetworkAccessManager is async only for current QT version 5.6, many people will need a synchronous version.

Comment: @RaidenCore Sync version will block your UI, that's why it was made async in Qt v4.7

Comment: Well, what if I want to use it in a console application without an event loop, again what if I want to use it in a UI application but inside another thread sequentially. The async version is a nightmare for certain scenarios in which the async version is nearly impossible to use. I say nearly because I suppose it is possible to use it in a very messy complicated state machines.

Comment: @RaidenCore Except the case without eventloop, you can use it pretty easily everywhere, even inside another thread if needed. I think it is more natural to write it using signal slots - it's not messy at all but cleaner. You better give it a try:)

Comment: You can not use anything async without an event loop man ! Ah by the way they are adding the sync mode to QNetworkAccessManager but still not documented ! you can find that in the new 5.6 QNetworkRequest::SynchronousRequestAttribute you can set it to true. but still not documented.

Comment: Actually there are lots of things which `QNetworkAccessManager` cannot do (at least not without very extensive amount of programming). FTP and SFTP are among them.